# handling large uploads on django, exceeding the max size on nginx

Tags: django, forms, file-upload, nginx, large-file-support

we have a django app on nginx where users upload media files. the media are huge such as 30min tv and radio programs resulting 100-300mb, and our shared hosting limits the upload to 30mb.

how to embed a smart uploader which will put chunks of 20-30mb instead of trying to upload the large file? we would like not to destroy our highly edited forms, so if there is an easy way to insert such tool as a bulletproof widget, you're awesome.

links, snippets, examples - highly appreciated, and any ideas are welcome. tx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider alternative hosting (perhaps a virtual private server), as for any serious downloads you will quickly run into the limits of your shared hosting.

Comment: I honestly hate MT, had them for 4 days when everything fcked up the first day and we waited for support 2 days, no thanks, rly. And more important: changing hosting was not my question!

Comment: MT or not, I think the suggestion of a different ISP is worth considering. Perhaps a virtual-private-server host if none of the "container" offerings suit?

Comment: Thanks for the links. I am now seriously evaluating moving to new hosting (Have only been with mt for a couple of weeks, already getting a little jaded)